# React: Perform different operation depending on select option dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6

I have the following form in React. What I want to do is send a POST request if the option from the select tag, is Participate.

```
<form action={this.props.action} method="POST" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <div className="ui action input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter code" name="code"/>
        <select className="ui compact selection dropdown">
            <option value="participate">Participate!</option>
            <option value="check_status">Check status</option>
         </select>
         <button>
             Submit
         </button>
     </div>
 </form>
```

This is my handleSubmit function:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // HERE I want to check if the option as Participate, and then to the following code:

    // Sudo code here
    // IF STATEMENT event.target.value.option === 'participate'

    const data = {id: this.state.code, is_winner: true};

    fetch('/api/add_user', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
        .then(res => res.json());

    // ElSE
    // DO NOT SOMETHING ELSE (NOT POST)
};
```

Comment: React forms are stateful. This means you need to store the value in your controller component. Once you've done that you can check the value from this.state. Read this page for how to use forms in React. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: @Kyle Are you saying that I need to save the option value in the state for my component on submit, and then use this.state.optionValue, for instance?

Comment: That is the recommended way, yes.

Comment: @Kyle Ok, just out of curiosity, how do I grab the value from the option? i know I can do this: this.setState({optionValue: event.data.option.value}), but I'm not sure how do I get the option value after I submit the form. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it the 'React' way you'll want to capture the select box onChange event:

```
<select onChange={e=>this.setState({selectedOption:e.target.value})} className="ui compact selection dropdown">
```

Then your condition check will be something like:

```
if (this.state.selectedOption === 'participate') {...
```

Comment: Sorry event.target.value.option is not a thing. It was just some pseudo code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend you to assign a **name** attribute to your `select` element like this

```html
<select name="my-dropdown" className="ui compact selection dropdown">
```

Then inside your **handleEvent** method you can access the values in your form

```
const elementRef = Array.from(event.target.elements).find(
  e => e.name === "my-dropdown"
);

// Here is the value from your dropdown selection
// that you can use to perform requests
console.log("Selection Value", elementRef.value);
```